# need more information about Trust anchor for certification path not found error

Tags: android, android-volley

I just want to know why the error :

```
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Only appear randomly and get resolve without action, I just have to wait and my application work again.

Thank's for you'r informations.

Comment: I have this problem as well. My app just randomly started throwing this error on a Login Activity after working for weeks. :-(